# How to return the value to a view from multiple selects in a if statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, multiple-select

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to figure out, how to create a view in which the price of a product changes accordingly - if it has a discount or not. How would I go about this? I think I'm reaching in the wrong direction. Probably something to do with JOINS?
Any suggestions are welcome!

```
CREATE VIEW AvailableProductsAndTheirPrices AS
SELECT Product.Name,

Product.Price,

InStock.Quantity, Store.Name, Store.Adress
FROM Product, InStock, Store
WHERE
InStock.Quantity > 0 AND
Product.PID = InStock.PID AND -- PID as in Product ID 
InStock.FID = Store.FID -- FID as in Store ID

GO
```

The `Product.Price` line would be replaced by something like this:

```
(SELECT IIF( (SELECT Product.PID NOT IN (SELECT Product.PID FROM Discount)),
             (SELECT Product.Price FROM .. how does this work?[1]), -- if there is no discount
             (SELECT Product.Price * Discount.Discount -- otherwise apply discount to price
              FROM Product, Discount
              WHERE Product.PID = Discount.PID AND GETDATE() <= Discount.To)
           ) 
),
```

[1] If I'm not mistaken, it would return the first row's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd recommend using the standard `JOIN` syntax.  Then you can use an `OUTER JOIN` to the `discount` table.

```
CREATE VIEW AvailableProductsAndTheirPrices AS
SELECT P.Name,
       P.Price * COALESCE(D.Discount,1),
       I.Quantity, 
       S.Name, 
       S.Adress
FROM Product P
       INNER JOIN InStock I ON P.PID = I.PID
       INNER JOIN Store S ON P.FID = I.FID
       LEFT JOIN Discount D ON P.PID = D.PID AND D.To > Now() 
WHERE I.Quantity > 0  
GOm
```

Comment: @Namphibian -- nice timing -- yours as well!

Comment: Just one thing - the code is missing an alias for one of the Name columns, otherwise just what I was looking for, thank you! A lot simpler and easier than what I was trying to do. I should probably get the hang of the JOIN syntax.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: I dont have table structures so the query below might not be 100%

Try something like the following query:

```
 CREATE VIEW AvailableProductsAndTheirPrices AS
  SELECT Product.Name, 
   Product.Price*COALESCE(Discount.Discount,1) AS Price
   InStock.Quantity, 
   Store.Name, 
   Store.Adress
  FROM Product
  INNER JOIN InStock
     ON Product.PID = InStock.PID
  INNER JOIN Store
     ON InStock.FID = Store.FID
  LEFT JOIN Discount
     ON Product.PID = Discount.PID
WHERE
 InStock.Quantity > 0 

GO
```

I am using a left JOIN to bring in discounts where a product does have a discount and if it does not have a discount use a NULL value. The coalesce function will then either use the discount if it has a discount otherwise it will just multiply the price by 1.